# is offline logic of apps considered backend

Tags: android, frontend, backend

Sorry I couldn't come up with a better title but I'm a bit confused what is considered my app's backend.

Frontend handles everything that the user sees.

Consider a that we are building an calculator app with Android.

The views(xml stuff) and the buttons and the listeners bound to them are considered front-end I guess. But on the `onClick` event we call some methods in a class that does the calculations(no calls to online APIs and such). Something like:

```
button.onClick{ textView.setText(core.add(a,b)) }
```

Everything in that expression besides the `core.add(a,b)` part is considered my front-end based on my understanding and that part is a function that goes to my backend. Even if we don't call to an online server my logics for how the data processing is done should be considered my backend or are there other terms for that?

Is my understanding right. Did I miss anything? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first take is you have a web tech background. Those terms, **back-end** and **front-end** are being generally used when an application (even web, mobile, desktop, embedded) is completely or partially depends on another stand-alone application on a server/local. This means that you have two different software, one acts as a provider of **data**, and there is a type of communication protocol(s) between them. You name it, it can be **REST**, **GraphQL**, **gRPC** so on so forth through any kind of base communication layer.

When it comes to that calculator example, the terminology, is quite different. Despite there are quite a lot of methods to decouple ***logic/processing*** parts of the application from the ***UI***, they are not as separate as what you can see in a web application. They are still running on same process and they don't act independently. For this domain, they are being called ***models***, ***views*** and ***controllers***. There are plenty of information over the internet about it. There is also a design pattern called MVC. There are other various design patterns that share the same concepts in other forms.

Edit: Your assumption on the definition of front-end (Frontend handles everything that the user sees.) is not correct. Front-end is the part of a web application that user directly **interacts** with. It means that it can still contain **view** and **controller** parts internally but they are being called front-end as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So basically following these design patterns where we separate the data from UI, the data part is not considered our back-end. Backend is term that is used only when we depend on another resource to get our data or results. But we do consider the UI part consisting of (Models,View, ViewModels, Data layer etc) to be our front-end right? So in the calculator example the whole app is just the front-end.

Comment: @ClassY No, the data part could be called ```model``` or even it can be generated in ```controller``` part. But the term ```back-end``` is not what an app developer uses. It doesn't make sense to call a part of your application which is shipped with your application binaries, back-end. That term (back-end) still can be used when you embed a service into your application and it acts as a local server. That's not something being commonly used. But who cares about terminologies then. Call it whatever you like as long as it just works good :)

Comment: Thanks again, but to just make things clear, whatever design pattern we choose(mvc, mvvm, mvp) even if our app doesn't need any backend, can we call these parts our app's frontend(the UI and handling it with any of these patterns)?

Comment: @ClassY When you have only one application that does not rely on a backbone, it's not relative to call it front-end. You probably need two ***ends*** to put a prefix (back & front) on them.